# Need to handle Credit card data in code securely c#

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

I am writing a C# Web API and passing "Credit card token"(555555*****5555) and other tokenScheme info as input parameter, I am calling third party API to detokenize my token and get the complete credit card number, the return type of the API is in JSON with other properties like "Status" and "ReferenceNumber" etc. I don't want to handle the json data in string data type and get the card details. And also I have a requirement to get the 10 digit value of the credit card number. Can suggest the best way to handle the data with out using string?

Currently I am using WebClient class with the UploadString to call the API Header Information headers:Content-Type: "application/json", the result set will be in json format.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json");
    var cardInfo = client.UploadString(url, "POST", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test));

    dynamic onj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cardInfo);
}
```

Comment: If the third party API is returning the data as a JSON string, there isn't really much you can do.

Comment: `card data in code securely c#` ← I am assuming you want to transmit the information securely. If that is the case always ensure you are transmitting over TLS version 1.2 or higher. Ideally it would be TLS 1.3 but not everyone supports this yet as the spec is not final/released. That ensures an encrypted end to end connection.

Comment: `I don't want to handle the json data in string data type` why? You could use a `Span<char>` or the bytes directly. But `SecureString` doesn't help much and its use is discouraged.

Comment: @MartinUllrich string data type will store the value in garbage collection which is easy for intruders to catch the information. If I use SecureString I doubt that I cannot able to read the 10th digit of the card number unless I convert to string. Is there any other method other than UploadString which could solve this issue.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md. If processes can access your memory, it doesn't really matter how short you keep data in memory for processing since the vulnerability is already there. you could also use arrays and override their values once you're done but that doesn't fix a vulnerability if it exists.

Comment: @MartinUllrich Can we use IDisposable interface and Disposable Method to clean up the garbage details. Does that work?